# Replace ng-include with code equivalent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

When composing my view out of various HTML partials, I prefer the declarative approach of placing an `ng-include` directive in my markup.

However a third party widget for a slideShow / carousel that I need to populate with items dynamically does not play well with the dynamic DOM changes of `ng-repeat` and `ng-include` (the third party widget will either accept a set of child nodes to be present in the DOM at the point in time the widget is initialized, or accept that new items are added programmatically by calling an `addItem` function).

```
<!-- this will not work properly, the items collection changes dynamically -->
<div id="slideShowHost">
    <div class="slideShowItem"
        ng-repeat="item in controller.items"
        ng-include="'templates/slideShowItem.html'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore I will replace the *slideShowHost* content with equivalent code in my controller. I use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load the content of *templates/slideShowItem.html* as one string, and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to create corresponding nodes from it for all my items. But this will not suffice as I use angular directives in the *slideShowItem* template that need to come to life.

```
// I'm using typescript here, but answers may as well use untyped javascript
var slideShowHost = $("#slideShowHost").acmeSlideShow();
require(["slideShowItemTemplate-html"], (itemTemplate: string) =>
{
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
    {
        let initializedItem = this.initAngularDependentItem(this.items[i], itemTemplate);
        slideShowHost.addAcmeSlideShowItem( initializedItem );
    }
});

...

private initAngularDependentItem(itemModel: any, template: string): any
{
    let itemView = $(template);
    // we have to create a scope here containing the itemModel
    // and we need to init the angular directives inside itemView
    return itemView;
}
```

Which code would be a correct and reliably working replacement for any `ng-include` where the included partial may use any *angular* directives and even nested *ng-includes*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $compile like this:

```
app.controller(function($scope, $compile) {
    var link = $compile(template);
    $('...').append(link($scope));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer given by jcubic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786846/replace-ng-include-with-code-equivalent/34786987#34786987) is correct. I'd like to add some detail.

We need to have the [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) injected into our controller, to compile the HTML string or the DOM created by jQuery; the resulting function has to be called to link scope and template together.
Therefore we also need to have the `$scope` injected.

The original use case contains an `ng-repeat` directive, which creates a child scope per each item and adds the corresponding item to it (besides [additional properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)). Thus we create child scopes from our controller's $scope programmatically to use those with the link function.

```
private static $inject = ["$scope", "$compile"];

...

private initAngularDependentItem(itemModel: any, template: string): any
{
    let itemDOM = $(template);
    let itemScope = this.$scope.$new();
    itemScope.item = itemModel;
    let link = this.$compile(itemDOM);
    let compiledAndLinked = link(itemScope);
    return compiledAndLinked;
}
```

**A word about child scope:**
My item template top-level node uses an [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) attribute-directive to assign an *itemController* per each item. **This directive creates new scope.**
The ramification of which is that the freshly per item created `itemScope` from my code snippet above is actually not the same object that the *itemController* will know as its very own $scope, but rather the *itemController*'s scope is a child-scope of the object we created. Keep that in mind. I tripped over this when my parent controller was supposed to read properties from the itemScope that the *itemController* allegedly set before.

We can set a shared object like so `itemScope.sharedObject = {}` and it will be the same for both because the childscope inherits it.